# Valor nothing em uma consulta a uma tag da xml usando linq .net

Tags: .net, xml, linq

Tenho a seguinte xml:

```
<ns1:TRetLote_GNRE xmlns="http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br" xmlns:ns1="http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br">
  <ns1:ambiente>1</ns1:ambiente>
  <ns1:situacaoRecepcao>
    <ns1:codigo>100</ns1:codigo>
    <ns1:descricao>Lote recebido com Sucesso</ns1:descricao>
  </ns1:situacaoRecepcao>
  <ns1:recibo>
    <ns1:numero>1600831117</ns1:numero>
    <ns1:dataHoraRecibo>2016-01-14 14:18:48</ns1:dataHoraRecibo>
    <ns1:tempoEstimadoProc>2000</ns1:tempoEstimadoProc>
  </ns1:recibo>
</ns1:TRetLote_GNRE>
```

E estou usando o seguinte código para pegar o valor da tag 'codigo'

```
   Dim xmlBase As String = retorno.OuterXml
   Dim xXml As XElement = XElement.Parse(xmlBase)
   Dim num As String = xXml.Elements("codigo").Value
```

Porém está retornando 'Nothing', pode ser o namespace da xml ?

Answer (score 0):

É preciso criar uma variável com o namespace e depois concatena-lo junto a tag de busca:

```
    Dim xmlBase As String = retorno.OuterXml
    Dim xXml As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlBase)

    Dim nspace As XNamespace = "http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br"

    Dim num As String = xXml.Descendants(nspace + "codigo").Value
```